# Getting text of a span that is not displayed

Tags: html, nightwatch.js

The web page I'm testing has a span with inner HTML having a numeric value that I want to extract.  For example:

```
<span class="timeout" style="display:none">5000</span>
```

I tried using the nightwatch command getText(), but it only returns "displayable" text, which, in this case, is a null string. What is the proper way to access this data?

Answer (score 2):

Figured it out myself. You can use getAttribute on "innerHTML" to get the value, e.g.,

```
browser.getAttribute(spanCSS,"innerHTML",function(r)
{   console.log("span's innerHTML is " + r.value)
})
```

Wonder if there is a list of these "reserved" attribute names somewhere.